# Upgrading single Domain Controller server from 2008R2 to server 2019

Tags: active-directory, domain-controller, upgrade

We have a client with a very old active directory environment on Windows Server 2008 R2.  We are going to replace it with a new server and would like to upgrade the existing server to keep all of the permissions and profiles in place.  We realize we will need to do it in a couple steps.  We created a Hyper-V server to test the upgrade.  During the initial attempt to upgrade to 2012 R2 we received an error indicating Forestprep and Domainprep need to be run.  The Forestprep completed successfully but Domainprep had issues with replication.  Long ago there was another server but it was decommissioned before we got the client so we don't have access to it.  I was able to manually remove the old server in sites and services to effectively disable replication.  Now I am getting a permissions error creating CN=TPM Devices,DC=CVV,DC=local in Active Directory Domain Services.  See log excerpt below:

```
[Status/Consequence]

The operation has not run or is not currently running. It will be run next.
[2024/02/13:16:51:53.609]
Adprep was about to call the following LDAP API. ldap_add_s(). The entry to add is CN=TPM Devices,DC=CVV,DC=local.
[2024/02/13:16:51:53.610]
LDAP API ldap_add_s() finished, return code is 0x10 
[2024/02/13:16:51:53.617]
Adprep was unable to create the object CN=TPM Devices,DC=CVV,DC=local in Active Directory Domain Services.

[Status/Consequence]

This Adprep operation failed.

[User Action]

Check the log file ADPrep.log in the C:\Windows\debug\adprep\logs\20240213165153 directory for more information. Restart Adprep.
[2024/02/13:16:51:53.621]
Adprep encountered an LDAP error. 

Error code: 0x10. Server extended error code: 0x57, Server error message: 00000057: LdapErr: DSID-0C090CB7, comment: Error in attribute conversion operation, data 0, v1db1


DSID Info:
DSID: 0x1811100d
ldap error = 0x10
NT BUILD: 9600
NT BUILD: 16384

[2024/02/13:16:51:53.628]
Adprep was unable to update domain information. 

[Status/Consequence]

Adprep requires access to existing domain-wide information from the infrastructure master in order to complete this operation.

[User Action]

Check the log file, ADPrep.log, in the C:\Windows\debug\adprep\logs\20240213165153 directory for more information. 

D:\support\adprep>netdom query fsmo
Schema master               Culinary01.CVV.local
Domain naming master        Culinary01.CVV.local
PDC                         Culinary01.CVV.local
RID pool manager            Culinary01.CVV.local
Infrastructure master       Culinary01.CVV.local
The command completed successfully.
```

I ran adprep /domainprep using an elevated command prompt logged in with an admin account belonging to Domain Admins and Enterprise Admins.  Anyone have an idea how to fix this error?

Additional command results requested by joeqwerty:

```
PS C:\Users\cvvadmin> echo $host
Name             : ConsoleHost
Version          : 3.0
InstanceId       : 9b5b8e7f-85bd-40c3-ba0b-b32a0f87f133
UI               : System.Management.Automation.Internal.Host.InternalHostUserInterface
CurrentCulture   : en-US
CurrentUICulture : en-US
PrivateData      : Microsoft.PowerShell.ConsoleHost+ConsoleColorProxy
IsRunspacePushed : False
Runspace         : System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.LocalRunspace

PS C:\Users\cvvadmin> Get-ADObject (Get-ADRootDSE).schemaNamingContext -Property objectVersion
DistinguishedName : CN=Schema,CN=Configuration,DC=CVV,DC=local
Name              : Schema
ObjectClass       : dMD
ObjectGUID        : f91149b0-619b-4ee8-90f1-3aa164846200
objectVersion     : 69

PS C:\Users\cvvadmin> Get-ADForest | fl Name,ForestMode
Name       : CVV.local
ForestMode : Windows2000Forest

PS C:\Users\cvvadmin> Get-ADDomain | fl Name,DomainMode
Name       : CVV
DomainMode : Windows2000Domain
```

PS outputs and domainprep log:

```
PS C:\Users\cvvadmin> Get-ADObject (Get-ADRootDSE).schemaNamingContext -Property objectVersion
DistinguishedName : CN=Schema,CN=Configuration,DC=CVV,DC=local
Name              : Schema
ObjectClass       : dMD
ObjectGUID        : f91149b0-619b-4ee8-90f1-3aa164846200
objectVersion     : 69

PS C:\Users\cvvadmin> Get-ADForest | fl Name,ForestMode
Name       : CVV.local
ForestMode : Windows2008R2Forest

PS C:\Users\cvvadmin> Get-ADDomain | fl Name,DomainMode
Name       : CVV
DomainMode : Windows2008R2Domain

PS C:\Users\cvvadmin> Dfsrmig /getmigrationstate
Unable to create DFSR Migration log file. Error 1307
All Domain Controllers have migrated successfully to Global state ('Eliminated').
Migration has reached a consistent state on all Domain Controllers.
Succeeded.

Domainprep log:

[Status/Consequence]

The operation has not run or is not currently running. It will be run next.
[2024/02/14:13:29:33.022]
Adprep was about to call the following LDAP API. ldap_add_s(). The entry to add is CN=TPM Devices,DC=CVV,DC=local.
[2024/02/14:13:29:33.025]
LDAP API ldap_add_s() finished, return code is 0x10 
[2024/02/14:13:29:33.033]
Adprep was unable to create the object CN=TPM Devices,DC=CVV,DC=local in Active Directory Domain Services.

[Status/Consequence]

This Adprep operation failed.

[User Action]

Check the log file ADPrep.log in the C:\Windows\debug\adprep\logs\20240214132932 directory for more information. Restart Adprep.
[2024/02/14:13:29:33.039]
Adprep encountered an LDAP error. 

Error code: 0x10. Server extended error code: 0x57, Server error message: 00000057: LdapErr: DSID-0C090CB7, comment: Error in attribute conversion operation, data 0, v1db1


DSID Info:
DSID: 0x1811100d
ldap error = 0x10
NT BUILD: 9600
NT BUILD: 16384

[2024/02/14:13:29:33.048]
Adprep was unable to update domain information. 

[Status/Consequence]

Adprep requires access to existing domain-wide information from the infrastructure master in order to complete this operation.

[User Action]

Check the log file, ADPrep.log, in the C:\Windows\debug\adprep\logs\20240214132932 directory for more information.
```

Comment: Can you include the output of: `netdom query fsmo`?

Comment: It was an ugly paste into a comment.  I added it to the code block above.

Comment: I guess the question at this point is **Culinary01.CVV.local** the existing server you're doing this from?

Comment: AS an aside, before you attempt the in-place upgrade again, make sure that SYSVOL has been migrated from FRS replication to DFSR replication. From a command prompt run **Dfsrmig /getmigrationstate** and make sure the state is **Eliminated**. If it isn't you need to take care of that prior to the in-place upgrade.

Comment: Yes, Culinary01 is the one and only DC. I tried to run the Dfsrmig command and got this:  D:\support\adprep>Dfsrmig /getmigrationstate

The current domain functional level is not Windows Server 2008 or above.
DFSRMig is only supported on Windows Server 2008 or above level domains.              Does this give any hint as to my domainprep issue?

Comment: You should definitely upgrade the domain and forest functional level to the highest level available on your DC before trying to upgrade. Why are you trying to upgrade it? Why not add a new DC, get it replicated and healthy and then decommission the old? In place upgrades are messy.

Comment: That is an interesting thought.  I have been in IT for over 40 years and done a lot of things but not very much with domain servers.  Mostly worked with small clients.  Can you give me some rough bullet points or point me to some existing documentation describing how to create the new DC and move all users/permissions/etc to it?  As for the functional level thats what I thought the adprep commands did.  (Wish I could do this with some C# code).  What we want to end up with is a healthy 2019/2022 DC as the main and then add another existing small 2019 server as another backup DC.

Comment: An in-place upgrade is fully supported by Microsoft. I personally perform them all the time for one of my MSP clients. I see no issues with doing them. They're often the most efficient, least error-prone methods of moving from an older OS to a newer OS.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/get-started/upgrade-overview#which-version-of-windows-server-should-i-upgrade-to

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/get-started/perform-in-place-upgrade

Comment: Your Upgrade Path: 2008R2>2012R2>2019

Comment: It would be cleaner to add another new DC, then demote the existing DC. The folder in question (TPM Devices) isn't even used any longer in AD.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Run the following commands from Powershell and post the output in your question:

```
Get-ADObject (Get-ADRootDSE).schemaNamingContext -Property objectVersion

Get-ADForest | fl Name,ForestMode

Get-ADDomain | fl Name,DomainMode
```

Then run the following command (where **domain.tld** is your AD name):

```
Set-ADForestMode -Identity domain.tld -ForestMode Windows2008R2Forest
```

Then from a command prompt work through these commands until the state is Eliminated:

```
Dfsrmig /getmigrationstate

Dfsrmig /setglobalstate 1

Dfsrmig /getmigrationstate

Dfsrmig /setglobalstate 2

Dfsrmig /getmigrationstate

Dfsrmig /setglobalstate 3

Dfsrmig /getmigrationstate
```

Then run forestprep/adprep from the Windows Server install media. Then proceed with the upgrade.

Then for good measure, run the following command from Powershell (where **domain.tld** is your AD name):

```
Enable-ADOptionalFeature 'Recycle Bin Feature' -Scope ForestOrConfigurationSet -Target domain.tld
```

And finally... when the upgrades are done run the following command from Powershell (where **domain.tld** is your AD name):

```
Set-ADForestMode -Identity domain.tld -ForestMode Windows2016Forest
```

Comment: Domainprep is still failing trying to create the object CN=TPM Devices,DC=CVV,DC=local.  I have added the latest output of the PS queries and the log excerpt form Domainprep to the bottom of the question.

Answer (score 0):

The domain ans forest functional level looks like Windows Server 2000. Windows Server 2016 is not supported in that level.

So you need add a domain controller with a operating systems version which supports Windows Server 2000. And then upgrade the functional levels.

---

Windows 2000 functional levels
Supported domain controller operating systems:

Windows Server 2008 R2
Windows Server 2008
Windows Server 2003
Windows 2000

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/identity/ad-ds/active-directory-functional-levels#windows-server-2008-r2-functional-levels

---

Another option would be to setup a new domain with a higher functional level and migrate everything over using ADMT

---

Edit

So for some reason adprep is not able to reach the infrastructure master Culinary01.CVV.local

Please test connectivity with `Test-NetConnection -ComputerName Culinary01.CVV.local -Port 389, 636`
And make sure that is your dns server in the network adapter settings

Also run dcdiag from a domain controller to verify if your domain is healthy

Comment: See the latest output pasted at the bottom of the original question.  Getting an error in Domainprep.

Comment: Okay so your forest and domain levels are at 2008R2, sorry I missed that. Adprep is saying it can't access the infrastructure master FSMO role. Check which machine has the infrastructure master role and why i can't be accessed `Get-ADDomain | Select-Object InfrastructureMaster`

Comment: PS C:\Users\cvvadmin> Get-ADDomain | Select-Object InfrastructureMaster

InfrastructureMaster
--------------------
Culinary01.CVV.local      It is the local server to be upgraded

Comment: I added a update to my answer

Comment: I also created a chat room https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/151487/upgrading-single-domain-controller-server-from-2008r2-to-server-2019?tab=general

Comment: Aha! It might be the DNS server.  I am testing on a Hyper-V image of the actual server.  I did not set the look at the network settings since I was working on a single DC.  I will look at this in the morning.

Comment: I still was not able to get Domainprep to complete successfully. After much more research I elected to add the new 2019 server to the domain and promote it.  Thanks for all the assistance.